# How can I separate a drain pipe from a sleeve protruding from the floor?

Tags: drain

I am assuming that this late 1940s, early 1950s, drain pipe, which goes into a pipe protruding up through the floor, is simply sealed there with putty. Is that correct?  Should it be dislodged and removed by twisting the drain pipe a few inches above the connection using a pair of channel-lock pliers?  The threads for the trap are completely corroded and it needs to be replaced.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the pipe was soldered into the sleeve.

Answer (score 0):

I would just cut the pipe 10" above the floor and go to a home store or plumbing supply and get the PVC fitting to reconnect the existing pipe to your sink. If you try to twist it you might damage it beyond repair and then you could be in some trouble...

Comment: Unfortunately that solution is not possible. The free-floating flange at the top of the drain pipe, which would screw down over the threads of the new trap, has crumbled apart. What you see there is the collar that fits over the floor tile. That flange was completely corroded and it fell apart. I have to remove the pipe from floor, if only to slip another connecting flange onto it, sliding it up from the base.

Comment: So you can't just cut that pipe 8" above the floor and install new fittings?

Comment: What kind of fittings do you mean? What would go onto the vertical pipe coming out of the floor, if it terminates say 8-12 inches above the floor?

Comment: A slip 90 and then you trap connector flange

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that compression slip couplings existed.   I don't know if they would pass local code. Will have to check.

Answer (score 0):

Channel-lock pliers probably won't do the job. You'll need two large pipe wrenches--one to turn the pipe and one to secure the sleeve so you don't tear it loose on the other end. Lefty-loosey.

After all that time they're probably good and stuck together. If you can't turn it initially, heat the sleeve with a plumbing torch, trying not to heat the upper pipe. This will cause it to expand and hopefully soften and release whatever gunk was used to seal the threads.

Comment: `lefty-loosey`. I don't think the sleeve is threaded. There's not enough room to turn the pipe 360 degrees.

Comment: Room? What do you mean?

Comment: The tiled wall behind the drain pipe is so close to the pipe that it would prevent the candy-cane shape drainpipe from turning 360 degrees in the sleeve.

Comment: Oh, well cut it off first.

Comment: I am trying to find out what it is that I have there, just as much as coming up with solutions.  If it were threaded, they couldn't have installed it in the first place so close to the wall.

Comment: Sure could if the coupler was turned instead of the drain stem.